# Getting Apache Camel to conditionally inject headers on the onException route

Tags: java-8, apache-camel

Java 8/Camel 2.19.x here. I have the following route XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:spring="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.0.0.xsd"
>
    <routeContext id="myRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route id="doStuff">
            <from uri="activemq:input"/>

            <onException useOriginalMessage="true">
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <redeliveryPolicy logStackTrace="true"/>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>

                <log message="${exception.stacktrace}" loggingLevel="ERROR"/>

                <!-- we get the original XML message - convert it to an object -->
                <unmarshal ref="xstream"/>

                <wireTap uri="bean:errorProcessor" copy="true"/>

                <rollback markRollbackOnly="true"/>
            </onException>

            <transacted ref="shared"/>
            <doTry>
                <unmarshal ref="xstream"/>
                <to uri="bean:thingProcessor"/>
        <marshal ref="xstream"/>
                <to uri="activemq:output"/>
            </doTry>
        </route>
    </routeContext>
</beans>
```

So, pretty simple:

1. On happy path, consume from the `input` queue on AMQ, deserialize it (via XStream) into a Java object, send it to the `thingProcessor`, and place the result of that processor on the `output` queue.
2. If an exception occurs, say the `thingProcessor` throws a `RuntimeException`, we log the exception stacktrace to the app logs, then we convert the original XML (that we consumed off the `input` queue), deserialize it into a POJO, and send it to the `errorProcessor` for handling. Finally we rollback the JMS transaction.

There will be times when the [`CamelFilePath` header](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) will be present on the message at the time of failure, and I'd like the `errorProcessor` to accept this and perform special logic if the header is present.

Currently my `errorProcessor` looks like:

```
@Component("errorProcessor")
public class ErrorProcessor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorProcessor.class);

    private final ErrorHelper errorHelper;

    public ErrorProcessor(final ErrorHelper errorHelper) {
        this.errorHelper = errorHelper;
    }

    public void handleErrors(
            final Fizzbuzz fizzbuzz,
            @Header("CamelFilePath") final String camelFilePath,
            @ExchangeProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT) final Exception exception) {

        // If camelFilePath is non-null and non-empty, do stuff with it here.

    }
}
```

Above, the `fizzbuzz` is the original (deserialized) XML/POJO that was consumed off the `input` queue.

#### My question

Sometimes the `CamelFilePath` header will be present on the message/exchange, and sometimes it won't be. How can I tweak my route so that *if* it exists on the "happy path" route, it will be copied over and present on the "error" route (that is, from inside the `<onException>` definition) as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use choice and simple clause in your route. 

I just know on java dsl, but to xml convert simply

```
.choice().when().simple("${header.CamelFilePath} != null && ${header.CamelFilePath} not contains ''").wireTap("bean:errorProcessor");
```

On xml it would be something like that:

```
<choice>
 <when>
  <simple>
    ${header.CamelFilePath} != null &amp;&amp; ${header.CamelFilePath} not contains ''
  </simple>
  <wireTap uri="bean:errorProcessor" copy="true"/>
 </when>
```